# LT3080 remote sense options?

Tags: remote-sense

I am considering building a programmable power supply using LT3080 LDO.

There are plenty of designs based on this IC, but I was unable to find the one with a true 4-wire (Kelvin) remote sense option.

Unfortunately, the negative feedback of the error amplifier of this IC is not accessible outside of the chip and the Vout voltage setting is done by adjusting a single resistor or by applying a voltage to the SET pin from DAC.

Belo please find one of the designs that I am considering as a base, it has a voltage divider and ADC to measure the output voltage of LT3080, but there is no closed loop control based on voltage directly measured on the load to compensate voltage drop on cables.

I am wondering if there is a way for adding a true remote sense option to this design by connecting the voltage divider and op-amp directly to the load and somehow closing the loop to have real-time compensation of voltage drop on cables.?

There is a red dotted line for illustration of the idea, is there a way to implement something like this , any ideas and suggestions?

Thank you in advance!

[image]